# Trouble combining Require.js and Backbone.js/Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I've read previous threads where other members have had identical error messages as me, but their accepted solution doesn't seem to help.

Basically I get this in Chrome console when I try to load index.html:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "underscore" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

A couple of seconds later this shows up:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: underscore,backbone
```

Chrome network tools doesn't show any anomalies everything up until day_view.js is loaded fine (200 OK).

**File structure**

[image]

**index.html**

```
...
<script>
        var require = {
            deps: ["jquery/jquery-min", "underscore/underscore-min", "backbone/backbone-min"]
        };
</script>
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
...
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',

    paths:{
        jquery:'jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore:'underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone:'backbone/backbone-min'
    },

    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore/underscore-min", "jquery/jquery-min"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        }
    },

    waitSeconds: 200
});

require(['day_view'], function (day_view) {
    function start() {
        day_view.render();
    }

    return {
        start:start
    };
});
```

**day_view.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
    function render() {
        ...
    }
...
```

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866740/loading-jquery-underscore-and-backbone-using-requirejs-2-0-1-and-shim

Comment: @jantimon I've read that one, but I can't see anything that helps with my current predicament. Is there anything in particular you think I should read? I've read this (http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded) too, but I can't find the cause there either.

Comment: try `shim = { ... deps: ["underscore", "jquery"] ... }`

Comment: @jantimon Doesn't work either. Same error message as in the question above.

Comment: Maybe `define('day_view', ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], ...`

Comment: try adding a slash in front of your `baseUrl`, like this `/scripts`

Comment: and also do what @jantimon said!

Comment: If I add the slash I need to make it "/html_client/scripts" or the path will be incorrect (Chrome says so). I adjusted the define in day_view.js to "define('day_view', ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {". Still doesn't work. Same error message. Everything seems loaded in the correct order according to chrome and I can use jquery, backbone and underscore in the console. Is my use of require special in any way? I mean, it shouldn't be this much work to "install" require.js, right? I've been at it for 8 hours soon. :-)

Comment: Wait a minute, I think you're right. It's not working (nothing is rendering), but I think you've answered my question and what I'm seeing now is something else. Care to make an answer that I can accept? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This finally worked.

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery:'jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore:'underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone:'backbone/backbone-min'
    },
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        waitSeconds: 15
    }
});

require(['day_view'], function (day_view) {
    function start() {
        day_view.show();
    }
    console.log(day_view); // Empty object here?
    return {
        start:start
    };
});
```

and

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) { ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the shim above, or you can also use jrburke's** AMD compatible fork of Backbone/Underscore:

https://github.com/amdjs/backbone

https://github.com/amdjs/underscore

This allows you to simply do:

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery:'jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore:'underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone:'backbone/backbone-min'
    }
});

define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) { ...
```

Frankly, I found the fork easier/cleaner/more robust than using a shim.

** FYI [jrburke](https://github.com/jrburke) is the creator of requirejs.

Answer (score 2):

PS Good news, Underscore 1.6.0 now supports requirejs define !!!

versions below this require shims, or requiring underscore.js then blindly hoping that the "_" global variable hasn;t been smashed (which to be fair is a fair bet)

simply load it in by

```
  requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "underscore": "PATH/underscore-1.6.0.min",
    }
  });
```

No shimming required :)