# requirejs: Module name "underscore" has not been loaded yet for context

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I always get this error when I freshly load my app,

```
Error: Module name "underscore" has not been loaded yet for context:
_. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded  

...,h){c=Error(c+"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#"+b);c.requireType=b;c.re...

require.js (line 8) TypeError: Backbone.Model is undefined  

var ProjectModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
```

But then they are gone when I hit the refresh button on my browser.

Does anyone know why? How can I fix it?

This is my config/ main/ entry js file,

```
require.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js',

    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-min',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone-min',
        text: 'lib/text/text'
    },

    shim: {
        jquery: {
          exports: '$'
        },
        underscore: {
          exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
          exports: 'Backbone'
        }
      }
});

require([
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'app',
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    // Pull in the Collection module.
    'collection/contacts'
], function(App){
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    App.initialize();
});
```

Have I missed something?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
shim: {
        jquery: {
          exports: '$'
        },
        underscore: {
          deps:["jquery"],
          exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
          deps:["jquery"],
          exports: 'Backbone'
        }
      }
```

Comment: thank you! it works beautifully now! can I ask why this change makes such a big different - what does `deps:[...],` mean? thanks!

Comment: deps  define the dependencies of AMD modules, because you don't have the "instance" of jquery for example inside backbone, and you tell that backbone depends from jquery. Glad to help you :) @lauthiamkok

Comment: Unless loading an ancient version of jquery, jquery needs no shim and shimming it *could* eventually lead to problems down the road.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774214/trouble-combining-require-js-and-backbone-js-underscore-js

Adding the backbone dependencies also helped me:

backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },