# Backbone.js and Require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I want to create Backbone.js app with Require.js.
But I have an error in console:  ***Uncaught Error: Module name "underscore" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])***

```
require.config({
        baseUrl: 'js/',
        paths : {
            'jquery' : 'jquery',
            'underscore' : 'underscore',
            'backbone' : 'backbone',
            shim: {
                'underscore': {
                    exports: '_'
                },
                'backbone': {
                    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                    exports: 'Backbone'
                }

            }
        }
    });

    define('app', ['jquery','backbone', 'underscore'], function ($, Backbone, _){

        var Model = Backbone.model.extend({});
        var model = new Model;
    });

    require(['app','jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore']);
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: try changing the order in define call to `jquery, underscore, backbone`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble combining Require.js and Backbone.js/Underscore.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774214/trouble-combining-require-js-and-backbone-js-underscore-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to list `underscore` as a part of `paths` so you can refer to it in the shims.  Also, not sure what your directory structure looks like, but I'm writing this with the assumption that library code is in the `/js/libs` directory).  Finally, note you won't need to `require` any of the dependencies of `app` -- the joy of RequireJS is that it'll figure out what to load.

So...

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/',
    paths : {
        'jquery' : 'lib/jquery',
        'underscore' : 'lib/underscore',
        'backbone' : 'lib/backbone',
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
       'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }

    }
});

define('app', ['jquery','backbone', 'underscore'], function ($, Backbone, _){
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    var model = new Model({
        foo: 'bar'
    });

    var app = {
        model: model
    };

    // ...

    return app;
});

require(['app'], function(App) {
    App.model.get('foo'); // <<=== returns 'bar'
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. But one correction:
    `App.model.get('foo'); `

Comment: Edited to match the example.  Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The shim is mentioned inside the paths object. I am not sure if that is the problem, but wanted to mention that here.

Answer (score -1):

You need [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as listed in your require statement.

Comment: Oh. I don't understand you. Can you show an example?

Comment: `require(['app','jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore']);` requires Underscore.js.  Download and link to it as you would any other JS file.

Comment: I've downloaded Underscore.js. It is in folder with other scripts.